# How to define a function pointers and and structure?

Tags: c, function-pointers

How to define a function pointers with a structure as parameter... and that structure contains the function pointer ?

This code doesn't compile :

```
typedef struct _INFOS_STRUCT {
    int val1;

    PTR_NEXT_ACTION nextAction;
    //void* (*nextAction)(struct _INFOS_STRUCT  * infos); // how to replace void* by PTR_ACTION* ?
} INFOS_STRUCT;
typedef void (*PTR_ACTION)(INFOS_STRUCT * infos);
typedef PTR_ACTION (*PTR_NEXT_ACTION)(INFOS_STRUCT * infos);

INFOS_STRUCT infos_list[10];
void run(int index){
    INFOS_STRUCT * infos = &infos_list[index];
        
    PTR_ACTION action = infos->nextAction(infos);
    while(action){
        action(infos);
        action = infos->nextAction(infos);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way:

```
//do the typedef first, on a forward declaration
typedef struct INFOS_STRUCT INFOS_STRUCT
typedef void (*PTR_ACTION)(INFOS_STRUCT * infos);
typedef PTR_ACTION (*PTR_NEXT_ACTION)(INFOS_STRUCT * infos);
struct INFOS_STRUCT {
    int val1;
    PTR_NEXT_ACTION nextAction;
};
```

Note: Changed the tag from `_INFO_STRUCT` to `INFO_STRUCT`. `_INFO_STRUCT` is a reserved name. You could use `INFO_STRUCT_` (not reserved) if you need the tag to differ from the `typedef` name.

---

Explanation:

The idea is simple. Once you forward declare a struct or union like with:

```
struct foo; 
union bar;
```

You can declare/define pointers to it such as

```
struct foo *ptr0;
union bar ***ptr1;
```

If the pointer definitions are in another struct/union definition that's at the same scope or at just plain in the same scope scope, you don't even need the forward declaration (note that function parameters, even in a declaration, are in a nested scope, so you do need the forward declaration in `struct foo; void takefooptr(struct foo*);`).

When you then follow a forward declare `struct foo` with `struct foo {  /*...*/ };` the type gets completed and you can start declaring actual `struct foo` variables rather than just pointers.

If want to skip the struct/union keyword in later uses, you can `typedef` the forward declaration:

```
struct foo;
typedef foo foo; //or typedef foo SOMENEWNAME;
```

or do it in one step

```
typedef struct foo foo;
```

As a quirk of the C standards, this forward-declaration thing is not allowed for enums. Structs and enums only.